# get the result of an sqlite select query javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

Simply want to add the result of a query to the variable. Not sure of the syntax when referencing the SQL, every Google search brings up the wrong thing.

snippet:

```
        function xrateQueryPound(tx){

            tx.executeSql('SELECT xrate FROM XRATES WHERE currency = "pound"', [], querySuccess, errorDB);
        }

        function querySuccess(tx, results){
            pound = results.rows.item(0).text;
        }
```

The part I'm unsure of is the `results.rows.item(0).text;` this is probably wrong, it should give me one value.

cheers.

Comment: You can use `console.log(results)` to examine the output. From there you should be able to get the value you want.

Comment: This shows "[object SQLResultSet]" not sure what this means. I know `results.row.length` gives me "1" which probably corresponds to the 1 result. But I want to extract that result as a string.

Comment: Try `results.rows[0].xrate`. I just checked the Github repo for `node-sqlite3` and it's annoying that they don't mention the result format anywhere (at least as far as I can see).

Comment: Yea it's hard to find how to call the right thing on results. That gives me an error "cannot read property 'xrate' of undefined" tedious.

Comment: Try `console.log(results.rows)`.

Comment: "[object SQLResultSetRowList]" not giving me much info to work with.

Comment: I just realized you're using `node-sqlite` and not `node-sqlite3`. According to their docs you should be able to access the value the way you attempted to in the code above - just change `results.rows.item(0).text` to `results.rows.item(0).xrate`.

Comment: Just saw this after I figured it out myself, legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

`results.rows.item(0).xrate`

thank you sholanozie.